# Remove text from toolbar

Tags: customization, tool-bar

my toolbar is filled with many buttons, and I'd like to know if it is possible to remove the text so it only shows the icon (and if it is possible, how to do it).
I currently have this :

[image]

But as you can see it is way too long, having just the icons would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it, because I hide the toolbar completely but if you add this

```
(setq tool-bar-style 'image)
```

to your init file, it should do the trick, like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178483/how-to-get-rid-of-text-beside-emacs-toolbar-buttons) SO answer.

Comment: See alsl [Toolbar+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#ToolBarPlus), which saves toolbar space in another way: a single menu name replaces the toolbar - click it to pop up the toolbar for a one-off use. IOW, toolbar on demand, when you want it.

Comment: Sorry for this late response, I didn't see my notifications. It works perfectly, thanks !